# Mongoose, ExpressJs - exposing mongo documents

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

Every example of using expressjs and mongoose are like that:

```
const contentTypes = await ContentType.find().sort({createdAt: -1});
res.json(contentTypes);
```

But in this scenario we are returning all document by REST api (even mongoose version field '_v'. I think it would be good practive to describe interface like this

```
export class ContentTypeEntry {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

and convert mongoose type to this interface object and return this DTO. I just starting using nodejs ecosystem, so maybe in this ecosystem returning directly ORM objects is normal?

How are You dealing with moongose objects and REST endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I got the question right, but this is what my response object looks like-

```
// GET /api/products/1010

{
    "meta": {
        "type": "success",
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Retrieved product number 1010"
    },

    "data": {
        "id": 1010,
        "name": "Apple iPhone X",
        "description: "Yada yada",
        "price": 1000
    }
}
```

This just separates the metadata and the actual returned data to make it easier for whoever is consuming the api to handle errors better. I also modify the JSON object to return only the required data and omit things like the version field from the response.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great question, even if it's a bit broad. There are lots of frameworks that build on top of Node/Express (for example, [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/)) to act as the glue between your data layer and your HTTP layer (REST, API, whatever you want to call it), deciding what you want to actually exist at a given endpoint. Happy to share other thoughts here if you have more specific questions.

You could also stay fairly lean and override the `toJSON` method of your Mongoose object (see [this](https://medium.com/@contactsunny/hide-properties-of-mongoose-objects-in-node-js-json-responses-a5437a5dbec2) for an example). This is probably in line with your example of having an additional class that your object will conform to before being delivered to the end user, but personally I'd prefer to keep that within my object definition (the Mongoose model file).

I suppose at the end of the day, it's a question of how much control you need, how big the project is going to be and what its future needs will be. For microservices, you may find that Express + Mongoose and a couple of specific strategies will solve your concerns.